# DataGrid (MS.toolkit_) UWP How to get SelectedItem

Tags: c#, uwp, datagrid

I try hard to find how to delete a row in the dataGrid (Microsoft Toolkit) in UWP app. I can't find any information about deleting at all. 
The table is populated from SQL database. I want to select a row and get the value of the needed item after pressing a Delete btn.
I can only get a RowNumber which is useless (or not??).
Begging for help. 
Thanks.

Xaml:

```
    <controls:DataGrid
        Grid.Row="1"
        x:Name="NotebookListDataGrid"
        Margin="12"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        AlternatingRowBackground="Transparent"
        AlternatingRowForeground="Gray"
        AreRowDetailsFrozen="False"
        AreRowGroupHeadersFrozen="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserSortColumns="False"
        CanUserReorderColumns="True"
        CanUserResizeColumns="True"
        ColumnHeaderHeight="32"
        MaxColumnWidth="400"
        FrozenColumnCount="0"
        GridLinesVisibility="All"
        HeadersVisibility="Column"
        IsReadOnly="False"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items1.DefaultItem}"
        RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed"
        SelectedItem="{x:Bind Items1.VarSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
        SelectionChanged="NotebookList_SelectionChanged" IsRightTapEnabled="False">
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Фамилия" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Модель телефона" Binding="{Binding Phone_model}"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Номер телефона" Binding="{Binding Phone_number}"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="E-mail" Binding="{Binding Email_adress}"/>
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
```

C# DataSource:

```
public class Notebook_List : BindableBase
{
    public Notebook_List() => IsLoading = false;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> DefaultItem { get; private set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    private Item _VarSelected;
    public Item VarSelected
    {
        get => _VarSelected;
        set
        {
            Set(ref _VarSelected, value);
        }
    } ...
```

C# action:

```
public Notebook_List Items1 { get; } = new Notebook_List();

private void AppBarButton_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //delete button
    {
        var deleteItem = Items1;
        textbox.Text = deleteItem.VarSelected.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Isn’t it just deleting the SelectedItem ‘VarSelected’ from the ItemsSource ‘Notebook_items’? The DataGrid is binding to a data source.

Comment: Yeah, but I get "a value cannot be null" when I'm trying to get the "VarSelected" value from the data source.

Comment: Is SelectionChanged event fired when you select a row? Is it fired again when you click the Delete button?

Comment: I already try to make it simple - display the value of "VarSelected" in a TextBox, and when I click the Delete btn i get the error. I googled a little, what if I do not need to create a new instance of class, i just need to get the value of "VarSelected" from the existing? (some code added above)

Comment: The ItemsSource is wrong, it should be an ObservableCollection, not an INotifyPropertyChanged ...You haven’t got the correct idea of binding to a collection of items, yet ;)

Comment: Please read [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart#binding-to-a-collection-of-items) on setting ItemsSource.

Comment: Thanks. Ive read it carefully. I've made some changes but still can't get the correct value. I get "NoteBook_UWP_c___no_.Models.Item" when I'm displaying the value in a textbox. (updated code is included).

Comment: If you call ToString() on an object, it will just print the type of the object, that is why you get that value in the text box. So you already get the VarSelected instance.

Comment: Ok. Is the any option to get the value of the selected cell?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your ItemsSource property of DataGrid bind to an **ObservableCollection< Notebook_item >** which provide change notification to UI when items are added or removed or a property of the list itself changes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a click event, try using a `Command` with the `CommandParameter={Binding}`.  In your code-behind, include a parameter of type `Item` in the command executed method.  From there, you should be able to use a LINQ query to remove the `Item` parameter without needing a reference to the row number or index of the source collection (if it derives from `List<T>`).